# Info path 2003 refuses to submit - 'The form does not contain any new data to submit to the datasource'

Tags: database, microsoft-infopath

**I have this error**

> InfoPath cannot submit the form
>   The form does not contain any new data to submit to the datasource

#### How can I fix this?

---

I've made a form in InfoPath specifying an access database for it to feed into; here is some info on the database.

- The database has a key field, as well as some text, numbers and
  boolean fields.
- The purpose of the form is to collect information from a survey - some yes/no questions and a unique identifer field
- I'm not using SharePoint as the version we have access to does not
  have branching/conditional formatting
- The form and database share the folder on a network drive.
- The form has a submit button, and a new record function, I got rid of the 'new query' button as I'm *not* querying the database, just adding new rows.
- I don't need all of the information to be submitted - some fields can/should be left blank.

I don't think I've missed anything, hopefully.

With all this, I am getting the above error: *InfoPath cannot submit the form
The form does not contain any new data to submit to the datasource*

I'm pretty certain that the form *does* contain new data, but despite scouring the interwebs I've found nothing on this error that was applicable to my situation.

How can I fix this error, so I can submit to the database?

Comment: Whilst it'll be a few days before I can submit a bounty on this, in fact it'll need to be after I get back form a trip, I promise to give a hefty (200+) rep-reward for anyone who can answer this by 12 GMT. If you think this'll be answered more quickly elsewhere, please let me know and I'll delete/repost there.